# Is any method with iphone broadcast message to others iphones without internet?

Tags: iphone, networking, p2p, broadcast

Is any method with iphone broadcast message to others iphones without internet?

If all iphones have the same program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth-based apps might do it.

Also, an interpreter of SMS messages should work. I've seen it on Symbian, with some script analyzing the 'codified' content of SMS's.

Comment: Bluetooth need connection to each phones :(

Comment: You can use 1 phone as a 'server' for the others. Another way is to use an Wi-fi network for connecting the phones.